# Converting projection in lat lon to pixel x y

Tags: coordinate-system, convert

I'm looking at a map at https://stephanwagner.me/create-world-map-charts-with-svgmap#svgMapDemoGDP

I think it is a Robinson projection but am not sure given that Antarctica is missing.

Is there a formula to convert a lat/lon in degrees to a pixel coordinate on the map given a width and height of the map?

This doesn't need to account for zooming.

The github repo is here: https://github.com/StephanWagner/svgMap

Comment: Even the SVG file doesn't give its projection. As you probably already guessed, Antarctica isn't included because it doesn't have a GDP. Comparing https://raw.githubusercontent.com/StephanWagner/svgMap/master/assets/map-optimized.svg to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_projection#/media/File:Robinson_projection_SW.jpg I agree it's probably Robinson. Perhaps assume Robinson, plot a few well known points and see if they end up in the right places? Or contact the git owner?

Answer (score 1):

I have written two functions in Python which convert between geographic & X-Y coordinates - see https://github.com/cmagagnosc/Map-projection

Most of the code consists of 19x4 arrays of cubic polynomial coefficients; the algorithms are (I hope) fairly easy to decipher from the remaining code, if you need the functions in a different language.

The precision isn't survey quality (if that matters - svgMap isn't either), but may be sufficient for your needs.

The functions are for a Robinson projection centered on the prime meridian & the equator.  I identified 16 check points on svgMap & got latlon from Google Earth, then converted them using RobinsonXY; then I did a conformal least squares fit.  I discarded 3 points as being outliers, and the remaining points were within about 2 pixels of the expected position on a 4000 X 2002 (pixel) svgMap; the transform resulting from the LS fit is

```
X(svgMap) = 1.011709731529x + 0.000423040689y + 116.896
Y(svgMap) = -0.000423040689x + 1.011709731529y - 69.734
```

where x & y are the values from the RobinsonXY function.

I also noticed that the svgMap height is a little less than a pole-to-pole Robinson projection (4000 pixels wide should be 2029 pixels high).

Comment: Doesn't proj4 have a Python library that does this?

Comment: Thank you, Barry Carter.  I was unaware of proj4; it does provide a more thorough set of forward & reverse functions.  The transformation I derived for svgMap may still be useful.